# Spring SFTP polling multiple directory using Outbound Message Gateway and IntegrationFlow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I want to get all file under a particular remote directory in a periodic manner. I am able to get the file under that directory only once after application startup. Not sure why the Poller is not working. This is registered in a spring boot project and the version is 2.2.1

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "sftpReportChannel",
            poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "5000"))
    public String filesForGET(){
        return "/etl/biq/autoscore/output/report-data/";
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpGetFlow(SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> csf) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("sftpReportChannel")
                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(csf,
                                AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.LS, "payload")
                        .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.RECURSIVE,  AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.NAME_ONLY)
                        //Persistent file list filter using the server's file timestamp to detect if we've already 'seen' this file.
                        .filter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "autoscore-meta-data")))
                .split()
                .log(message -> "file path -> "+message.getPayload())
                .handle(Sftp.outboundGateway(csf, AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.GET, "'/etl/biq/autoscore/output/report-data/' + payload")
                        .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.STREAM))
                .handle(new ReportHandler()) //get the payload and create email content and send eamil to recipients
                .get();
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you add new files into that dir at runtime? You said it your self `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. So, the same file from that dir is not going to be picked up. Or you can modify that file and `mtime` of the remote file should be changed...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Great hints! Yes, that is the reason. Now it is working fine. Thank you again, it save my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.filter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "autoscore-meta-data")))` makes it working the way that it doesn't pick up the same file again and again on the subsequent poll activities.

Make sure you add new files in that remote dir at runtime or modify already processed file. The `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` logic relies on the `mtime` property of the `LsEntry` to determine that the file has been changed therefore it is good for processing again.